# why my bootstrap css class didn't have any effect in my index.html.erb?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap to create one main page,i add gem 'bootstrap-sass' into gemfile and add some components in my page. but it didn't work.
so i uninstall bootstrap-sass gem.
instead of, i download bootstrap file,copy them into my different directory. but it also didn't work.who can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

u need to add your downloaded bootstrap css and js file in your vendor. And then require it, in application.css and application.js .

Answer (score 0):

The **[Rails and Bootstrap](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap)** example app will show you how to integrate Bootstrap with Rails using the bootstrap-sass gem. The bootstrap-sass gem is recommended because it works with the Rails asset pipeline.

The easiest way to set up a Rails application with Bootstrap is to use the [Rails Layout](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_layout) gem. Here's how:

In your Gemfile, add:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
group :development do
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
```

Be sure to run "bundle update". A generator provided by the rails_layout gem will set up Bootstrap and add the necessary files. Run:

```
$ rails generate layout:install bootstrap3
```

The rails_layout generator will rename the file:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

to:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
```

This will allow you to use Sass syntax in your application stylesheet. Stylesheets can use variables, mixins, and nesting of CSS rules when you use Sass.

The rails_layout generator will create the file:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/framework_and_overrides.css.scss
```

and modify the file:

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

The gem will create or replace four files:

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
app/views/layouts/_messages.html.erb
app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb
app/views/layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb
```

See the [Rails and Bootstrap](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap) example app to see how these files set up a navigation bar, flash messages, and application layout for Rails.

Comment: it didn't work.I am confused so much.any other idea can u tell me?

Comment: Try cloning the [Rails and Bootstrap](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap) example app from the repo or use [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) to create a starter app.